# Combine multiple deferred values into a new deferred type in Sangria, GraphQL Implementation

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

We have two endpoints (backend calls) which return different but relevant data types `XData` and `YData`. If an instance of `XData` exists with id `1`, then there must be an instance of `YData` with the same id `1`.

We have created a fetcher for each data type `xFetcher` and `yFetcher`. These fetchers are used separately in our GraphQL query to fetch data from both endpoints, but for some use case we want to combine data retrieved from both of them using a specific id, e.g., `1`. This combination might not be a simple list append, as shown in the example below.

As `XData` and `YData` are queried also separately in other parts of the query, we cannot simply merge these two resolvers into one, and we are trying to avoid doing multiple calls to the same endpoint if possible.

I have created a simplified example for this use case. How can we return one deferred value combining data retrieved from two fetchers?

```
case class Ctx()
case class XData(id: Int, a: Seq[String], b: String)
case class YData(id: Int, a: Seq[String], c: String)
case class Data(id: Int)

val xFetcher = Fetcher((ctx: Ctx, ids: Seq[Int]) => Future {
  ids.map(id => XData(1, Seq.empty, "")) // Back end call to (endpoint X)
})(HasId(_.id))

val yFetcher = Fetcher((ctx: Ctx, ids: Seq[Int]) => Future {
  ids.map(id => YData(1, Seq.empty, "")) // Back end call to (endpoint Y)
})(HasId(_.id))

val GData = deriveObjectType[Ctx, Data](
  AddFields(
    Field("a",
      ListType(StringType),
      resolve = ctx => getA(ctx))
  )
)

def getA(ctx: Context[Ctx, Data]) = {
  val id = ctx.value.id

  // Here I should also get an instance of `YData` and return the
  // combination of the sequences `a` in both instances (xData, yData)
  val xData: XData = ??? //getDeferredXData()
  val yData: YData = ??? //getDeferredYData()
  val desiredOutput = xData.a ++ yData.a

  // I can get `a` from one instance but not both of them together
  DeferredValue({
    val xData = xFetcher.defer(id)
    // val yData = yFetcher.defer(id)
    // How can we combine both into one deferred value?
    xData
  }).mapWithErrors { data => (data.a, Vector.empty) }
}
```

I haven't used Sangria much, so please excuse any unclear information related to `deferred resolvers` or `fetchers`

Answer (score 1):

The description of your scenario sounds quite similar to this issue:

[Add additional items to per-request cache](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/issues/377)

It is already implemented, but not released yet.

Also, if it ok to always load `XData` and `YData` together, then you can define a fetcher for the tuple `(XData, YData)`. Then in the resolver, you can extract a needed object from the tuple. Something like this:

```
DeferredValue(fetcher.defer(id)).map {case (xData, yData) ⇒ xData}
```

Comment: Thanks for the new feature and for your reply. I think it might help if we cache `XData` when first queried and then access this cache when we need `YData`. `YData` in our case is extended data that is accessed when needed, and this data is fetched not only from one service but also from about 5 more. `XData` is very big and always returned and that's why it is important to use the fetcher of it to reduce hitting the service of `XData` when querying the extended one. If you think I should elaborate more and create a new issue, please let me know.